# Choose recipes to maximize usage of ingredients - what is the name of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, resources

I am quite new to the algorithm world, still learning. And I received a task called "Milkshakes". The task gives you the products and recipes. For example, you know the product amounts of: milk, chocolate, sugar, whitechocolate, sprinkles... and have recipes like "chocolate milkshake", "whitechocolate milkshake", "simple milkshake". The task is to use the products as efficiently as possible (so that there would be minimal leftovers), to make different cocktails. I don't need the solution, I just want to know the algorithm type, that solve these kind of problems.

Comment: I'm assuming that your code should create as many cocktails as possible, or is it that only leftovers should be min?

Comment: I did not understand what is the required output but it seems like a max flow matching problem.

Comment: The task does not mention the cocktail count, but I assume it would be better to have more cocktails for the same cost :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the multi-dimensional knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem

Your product inventory is the knapsack, ingredients are dimensions and cocktails are the items being packed.